# Loop through all controls on form and if event exists on control add handler to control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, reflection

Pseudo code of how I expect it to work but I am not sure what .net methods I need to call to accomplish this.

```
    Dim specifiedEvent = "MouseDown"
    Dim handler = handler
    For Each control As Control in form.controls
      If control has specifiedEvent Then

        control.specifiedEvent addhandler handler

      End If 
    Next
```

c# is linked because it can be easily converted to vb

Comment: Although you could do this using reflection to find the specified events, the problem here is specifying the handler code. How would you expect the handler to look? Different events can have different arguments.

Comment: @MatthewWatson in .net i think handlers have to have a specific definition acording to what event they are handling. so i would expect it to have the appropriate definition for mousedown in this case since i am searching for mouse down.

Comment: Is this just for `MouseDown`? Every `Control` has a `MouseDown` event....no need to check.

Comment: Do you want to know whether the event exist in the class or whether it is hooked up in an instance?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not so good at VB, so here my C# try:

```
foreach(Control c in form.Controls)
    c.GetType().GetEvent(specifiedEvent)?.AddMethod?.Invoke(c, new object[] {handler});
```

`Type.GetEvent()` returns an `EventInfo` for the event with the specified name or `null` if no such event exists.

The `AddMethod` property of this `EventInfo` is the `MethodInfo` of the add method of that event.

This is C# 6. So you might have to add extra `null` checks (where I use the null propagation/null conditional operator `?`) to check if the event really exists.

---

If your question is only about the `MouseDown` event, then it's a little bit strange, because the `Control` class itself declares the `MouseDown` event. So *every* class inherited from `Control` has this event (except your dealing with classes that are intentionally hiding this event). So you could simply add the event to all `Control`s:

```
foreach(Control c in form.Controls)
    c.MouseDown += handler;
```

Comment: Am I paranoid or is somebody hunting me? This is the third time _today_ I get a downvote with no explanation on an otherwise well received answer...

Comment: Annoying when that happens. People should at least give an explanation (unless it's obvious what the problem is - which is not the case here).

Comment: The answer I was going to give was the same as your comment about every control having a `MouseDown` event. I'm not the downvoter, but maybe that's the better answer? I was going to answer but no point in duplicating your comment.

Comment: Note that there is no method called `AddMethod()` in type `EventInfo`. Did you mean to put something else there?

Comment: @MatthewWatson there is no method `AddMethod()`, it is a _property_ of type `MethodInfo`. This is the `MethodInfo` for the _method_ that adds the handler to the event.

Answer (score 1):

As people have already pointed out, if you are only looking for "MouseDown" then there is no need to check.

But if you need an approach using reflection that will attach a handler to an event given the name of the handler and the name of the event as strings, then you can do it like this.

This code attaches the event handler to each control nested in a container control with an event which matches the supplied name:

```
public void HookUp(Control container, string handlerName, string eventName)
{
    MethodInfo eventHandler = this.GetType().GetMethod(handlerName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (var control in container.Controls.Cast<Control>())
    {
        var ev = control.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);

        if (ev == null)
            continue;

        var d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(ev.EventHandlerType, this, eventHandler);
        ev.AddEventHandler(control, d);
    }
}
```

As an example, your mouse down handler would look like this:

```
private void mouseEventHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Button);
}
```

And you could call it from an appropriate place (such as a Form constructor) like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    HookUp(this, "mouseEventHandler", "MouseDown");
}
```

Note the following:

1. This seems an odd thing to want to do. I feel like there's going to be a much better way to approach your problem (it sounds like an X-Y problem).
2. This does NOT unsubscribe from the event. You'd have to do that in the form's dispose method using a similar kind of code, only calling `.RemoveEventHandler()` instead.